# How do I avoid one 'click' that triggers two functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have two JS functions:

1. `$('button').click(function()`  inside `$(document).ready`
2. `$(document).on('click','button', function()`

**the second function is design for buttons that I dynamically generated.
The problem I have is that when I click the button that associates with first function, the second function also gets triggered. How can I avoid this?**

PS: since I give names to each button and this conflict is not affecting functionalities at all, but I think that one click trigger two function is not very smart :(

Comment: you do not need separate function for dynamically added elements. Code should work if you delete one of two

Comment: try to insert an ID every different buttons.

Comment: How about adding different class for generated buttons and pre defined buttons?

Comment: try, $('button').click(function (e) {e.stopimmediatepropagation(); }.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because of event propagation.

You can stop the event propagation in the first handler to prevent the dynamic handler from being fired.

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    //your code
})
```

But a more appropriate solution will be to add a common class to all the dynamic button elements and target only them with the delegated handler like

```
<button class="mydynamic"></button>
```

then

```
$(document).on('click','button.mydynamic', function(){
});
```

Comment: But isn't it more efficient to listen only to an element around the buttons for clicks than to listen on the whole document?

Comment: @DanielBudick yes... it will be much efficient to if we can attached the handler to the immediate static ancestor of the dynamic elements

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your dynamicly generated buttons into a div:

`<div class="wrap">...buttons... </div>`

and listen on the div:

`$('.wrap').on('click','button', function(){});`

It will be more efficent.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for `event.stopPropagation()`  [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)